# Multiple queue for Celery daemon

Tags: python, celery, init, celeryd

I have a network of Celery servers and workers that are to be used for a high volume I/O task coming up.  There are two queues, `default` and `backlog`, and each server has five workers. All servers are daemonized with a configuration much like the [init script config](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd) documentation.

What I'd like to do for one server is have three workers for `default` and two for `backlog`.  Is it possible to do this with a daemon configuration?

Comment: Take a look at [`queues`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues)

Comment: I already have queues set up.  I just want to daemonize them so two queues can work on one server with an init script

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-configuration) in this part whare it shows you an example configuration it also says:

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples):
```

So as you can see is possible to have celeryd starting multiple nodes and you can configure each of them via CELERYD_OPTS, therefore you can set different queue for each of them.

[Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html) you found another more complete example of celery multi, I post here a little extract.

```
# Advanced example starting 10 workers in the background:
#   * Three of the workers processes the images and video queue
#   * Two of the workers processes the data queue with loglevel DEBUG
#   * the rest processes the default' queue.
$ celery multi start 10 -l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data
    -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG
```

Comment: Interesting find.  I already define the workers specifically in `CELERYD_NODES`, but the rest I did not know.

Comment: Basically add in CELERYD_OPTS the arguments as accepted by celery multi like "-l INFO -Q:1-3 images,video -Q:4,5 data -Q default -L:4,5 DEBUG" off course don't forget to add multiple worker names in CELERY_NODES